# GStreamer image to rtsp using rtspclientsink

Tags: video, encoding, streaming, pipeline, gstreamer

New to GStreamer,
I want to stream a simple JPEG to rtspclientsink

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v multifilesrc location="image.jpg" caps="image/jpeg,framerate=1/1" ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! videoscale ! video/x-raw,width=1280,height=1024,framerate=1/1 ! x264enc speed-preset=veryfast tune=zerolatency bitrate=800 ! rtspclientsink location=rtsp://localhost:8554/test
```

The above pipeline works, but I think there is a lot of unnecesary plugins I'm using.
What I want to achieve is very simple, just send the image to the rtspclientsink with the height, width, 1 framerate per second.

This takes a lot of CPU
Eventually I want to be able to view the localhost stream.
What am I doing wrong?

Going through all GStreamer docs with no luck!